# Importing external JS Library to Angular 2 CLI @NgModule

Tags: angular, dropzone.js, angular-cli

so I've been using this [article](http://sharpten.com/blog/2016/08/06/using-dropzone-js-angular-2.html) to get Dropzone.js imported into my Angular 2 project via Angular CLI. Though this article was published a little over 2 months ago before this question, I'm noticing this person wasn't use the new Angular CLI syntax with @NgModule.

Is there a way I can import this [Dropzone.js npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dropzone) into my project?

I've managed to include the Dropzone.js file into my "scripts" property in angular-cli.json here:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/dropzone/dist/dropzone.js"
      ],
```

Here is my dropzone component:

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit,
    Input,
    Output,
    EventEmitter,
    ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    Http
} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'dropzone',
    templateUrl: './dropzone.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dropzone.component.scss']
})
export class DropzoneComponent implements OnInit {

    private _dropzone: Dropzone;

    @Input()
    element: string = ".dropzoneArea";

    @Input()
    url: string = "file/post";

    @Input()
    uploadMultiple: boolean = false;

    @Input()
    maxFileSize: number = 2048;

    @Input()
    clickable: string = ".dropzoneArea";

    @Input()
    autoProcessQueue: boolean = true;

    @Input()
    addRemoveLinks: boolean = false;

    @Input()
    createImageThumbnails: boolean = false;

    @Input()
    previewTemplate: string = "<div style='display:none'></div>";

    @Input()
    acceptedFiles: string = "*";

    @Output()
    sending: EventEmitter < boolean > ;

    @Output()
    uploadprogress: EventEmitter < number > ;

    @Output()
    success: EventEmitter < any > ;

    @Output()
    error: EventEmitter < any > ;

    constructor(private _eleRef: ElementRef, private _http: Http) {

        this.sending = new EventEmitter < boolean > ();
        this.uploadprogress = new EventEmitter < number > ();
        this.success = new EventEmitter < any > ();
        this.error = new EventEmitter < any > ();

    }

    initDropzone() {

        this._http.get("api/getCsrf").subscribe(data => {

            let body = data.json();

            this._dropzone = new Dropzone(this.element, {
                url: this.url,
                uploadMultiple: this.uploadMultiple,
                maxFilesize: this.maxFileSize,
                clickable: this.clickable,
                autoProcessQueue: this.autoProcessQueue,
                addRemoveLinks: this.addRemoveLinks,
                createImageThumbnails: this.createImageThumbnails,
                previewTemplate: this.previewTemplate,
                acceptedFiles: this.acceptedFiles,
                params: {
                    _csrf: body._csrf
                }
            });

            this._dropzone.on("sending", (file, xhr, formaData) => {

                this.sending.emit(true);

            });

            this._dropzone.on("uploadprogress", (file, progress, bytesSent) => {

                this.uploadprogress.emit(progress);

            });

            this._dropzone.on("success", (file) => {

                this.success.emit(file);

            });

            this._dropzone.on("error", (file, message) => {

                this.error.emit(message);

            });

        });

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.initDropzone();

    }
}
```

And here is the error I get when I load my app

```
client?93b6:76 [default] /projects/project/dropzone/dropzone.component.ts:79:33 
Cannot find name 'Dropzone'.
```

Anyone have any thoughts on this? I actually can access the Dropzone object, as it's attached to the Window, but I can't get my component to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't know anything about JS files, so if you have something global you still need to tell TypeScipt about it, one way or another. The easiest way would be to just declare an arbitrary variable

```
declare var Dropzone: any
```

This would be enough to compile the code, as TypeScript is simply looking for a name `Dropzone`. And because we type it to `any`. it doesn't really care what we do with that symbol afterwards. It just accepts that we know what we're doing with it.

When using JS libraries with TypeScript, it's more preferred to use the TypeScript definition file though. If the library doesn't support TypeScript out the box (doesn't have it's own definition file include in the lib), for popular libraries, there is most likely already a definition file out there.
Dropzone is one of those popular libraries.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/dropzone
```

Now you can import it wherever you need it

```
import Dropzone from 'dropzone'
```

Now you should get strong typing and intellisense. Note that for me, using VSCode, I had to restart the IDE for the intellisense to kick in. This should not be required, it might be a VSCode bug.

Comment: Hey @peeskillet, thanks for the answer. When I installed the typings, I tried to `import Dropzone from 'dropzone' in @NgModule and it says the module can't be found. When I try `declare var Dropzone: any` inside of my Dropzone component, it gets rid of one of the Dropzone errors, but I still get this one: 

`main.bundle.js:58546 [default] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ll-client-web/src/app/dropzone/dropzone.component.ts:13:23 
Cannot find name 'Dropzone'.`

Comment: You might need to update your global TypeScript to the latest. `@types` support isn't added until TypeScript 2.0. Or maybe your IDE doesn't support `@types` yet. Try to build it from command line and see if it's not just an IDE problem

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not 100% sure what you mean. How can I check what version of Tyepscript I have? What can I do to build it from the command line?

Comment: To check just do `tsc -v`. `tsc` is the typescript compiler that comes with the npm installation of `typescript`. If it's earlier than 2.0, just install a new one `npm install typescript -g`.. I meant build your project. If it's just an IDE problem, then the project should build fine, unless you have an older version of typescript installed. To build it you can just `ng build` or `ng serve`

Comment: Ah okay, I got it. I needed to restart the project as well. Derp. Thanks so much @peeskillet, you're awesome :D