# Including externalJs libraries

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Js library that I need to include into my project. I have currently added it into the head of main HTML document as I normally would. I have called methods from this library within my angular2 typescript app and it works fine, however, it always flags an error saying

> Cannot find name 'TheJsLib'.

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference javascript file inside typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274278/reference-javascript-file-inside-typescript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing external JS Library to Angular 2 CLI @NgModule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098443/importing-external-js-library-to-angular-2-cli-ngmodule)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tell typescript, that indeed the methods you use do exist, for example:

`declare function escape(s: string): string`

Or if it is a variable:

`declare var Dropzone: any`

Answer (score 1):

You can import and declare your external object. after then you can use it in your component.

```
import 'external.js'
declare var myExtObject: any;
```

I made an example in plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/b2kAztHntMuNjTfOv8jD?p=preview

Comment: It's an external file unfortunately and when I am importing it as suggested I get CORS errors

Comment: Why you just simply don't copy code of that file and create your own ? @Johnwilliams